# No serializer associated with the filename or extension "true"?

Tags: java, sql, maven, liquibase, changelog

I get that error when I run the command "mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog". I have

```
  <outputChangeLogFile>true</outputChangeLogFile>
```

in order to print the output in a changeLog file rather than the command prompt. If I remove that line, there is no error. These are my properties

```
<changeLogFile>src/main/Resources/liquibase-3.3.3-bin/db.changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</url>
    <username>****</username>
    <password>********</password>
<promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
<outputChangeLogFile>true</outputChangeLogFile>
```

For dependencies I have mysql-connector, liquibase-core and snakeyaml.

[INFO] Can not use class liquibase.serializer.core.json.JsonChangeLogSerializer as a Liquibase service because org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer is not in the classpath.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/liquibase-generatechangelog-failed-org-yaml-snakeyaml-representer-representer

Answer (score 2):

`<outputChangeLogFile>` is not a `true/false` boolean but a `String` where you are supposed to hand in a complete file path for the changeLogFile, e.g.:

```
<outputChangeLogFile>c:/tmp/myGeneratedChangeLogFile.xml</outputChangeLogFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

What *Jens* suggested is true for your case but the error "No serializer associated with the filename or extension" can also happen when you are trying e.g. to generate the output changelog through the `liquibase-maven-plugin` with the command

```
mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog
```

and have specified only the plugin without the dependency in the `pom.xml` file, e.g.:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.16.1</version>
  <configuration>
     <propertyFile>src/main/resources/config/application.yml</propertyFile>
     <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-root.xml</changeLogFile>
     <url>jdbc:h2:file:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</url>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But after specifying the dependency in the dependencies section as well e.g.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and after correctly specifying the path for the output changelog, the error should not appear anymore. (Just as an observation for future readers)